# NSURLConnection connectionDidFinishLoading not being called while other delegate methods works

Tags: delegates, nsurlconnection

I try to use light modified example from book "Programming IOS 6"
I have wrapper class for NSURLConnection:

```
@interface WCDHTTPHandler : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSURLConnection* connection;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSData* receivedData;
  - (id) initWithRequest: (NSMutableURLRequest*) req;
  - (void) cancel;
@end

#import "WCDHTTPHandler.h"
@interface WCDHTTPHandler()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSURLConnection* connection;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableURLRequest* request;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableData* mutableReceivedData;
@end

@implementation WCDHTTPHandler

-(NSData*) receivedData {
    return [self.mutableReceivedData copy];
}


- (id) initWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *) req {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self->_request = [req copy];
        self->_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
        self->_mutableReceivedData = [NSMutableData new];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Receive HTTP response");
    [self.mutableReceivedData setLength:0];
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"Receive HTTP data");
    //NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"%@", result);
    [self.mutableReceivedData appendData:data];
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Receive HTTP error");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        postNotificationName: @"connectionFinished"
        object: self
        userInfo: @{@"error": error}];
}


- (void) connectionDidFinishingLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Finish HTTP loading");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connectionFinished" object:self];
}


//- (void) connectionDidFinishingDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL {
//    NSLog(@"Finish HTTP downloading");
//}


- (void) cancel {
    [self.connection cancel];
    self->_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                            initWithRequest:self->_request
                            delegate:self
                            startImmediately:NO];
}


@end
```

I initialise and use this wrapper in ApplicationDelegate.m:

```
@interface WCDAppDelegate()
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) WCDHTTPHandler *httpHandler;
@end

@implementation WCDAppDelegate

NSString *requestString = @"blalblala";
NSData *requestBody = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SRV_URL]
                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                timeoutInterval:15.0];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setValue:@"utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-charset"];
[request setValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestBody];
self.httpHandler = [[WCDHTTPHandler alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(httpRequestDone:)
    name:@"connectionFinished"
    object:self.httpHandler];
NSLog(@"Start HTTP");
[self.httpHandler.connection start];
return YES;
```

I made wrapper object like a property because, i was afraid that after execution of AppDelegate method NSURLConnection could lost connection to its delegate, but seems that it doesn't make any sense.

It works. But not fully. Delegate callbacks DidReceiveResponse and DidReceiveData are called, and i receive all expected data from web server. But callback connectionDidFinishingLoading are not being called. In related topics someone suggest to compute how many data is left and when expected data length is equal to 0 do all actions that i want to do in connectionDidFinishingLoading. But it is look like a hack.

Comment: is there a particular reason why are you using old NSURLConnection api?(By old I mean delegation because you can use new block api much more easily)

Comment: Hey guys, you know what... I'm idiot i write connectionDidFinishingDownloading instead of connectionDidFinishDownloading

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new block based NSURLConnection api and It is really easy to implement

```
    NSURLRequest *request=...;
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    }];
```

Comment: I read about this and i suppose that this way is not new api its just another method with some advantages [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-SW1). But thank you, i did not pay attention to this solution, i spent all time for trying to make working "Retrieving the contents of a URL using a delegate object" (because in book author explains this method). I will try to use your suggestions. But anyway i'm interested in why my code doesn't work.